# Using jpeg tiles in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

As far as I can see, leaflet uses ".png" images for its tiles.

```
var mapOnlineUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
```

Is there a way I could use jpeg images ? I am working on an offline mapping solution and the arial views quickly add up to huge sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't have any tiles. Your tileprovider does. In this case `openstreetmap.fr`. Since they've decided to use `png` files, you're stuck with that format. They are using that format because it's the smallest size (uses the lowest bandwidth) for that particular tileset. These free tilesets get used by a huge amount of users all over the world and it would be rather expensive for them to not have them properly optimized.

That's said most (i think) satellite imagery tilesets are in `jpg` format, here's an example of mapquest satellite tile:

http://oatile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/15/5240/12661.jpg

Leaflet merely renders tiles from the tileserver you provide, in a grid using HTML `img` elements. It doesn't matter if use `png`, `jpg`, `gif`, `bmp` or something else in Leaflet, as long as your targeted browsers support that encoding format with the `img` tag.

Comment: I apologize for the noob question but your answer explained well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This question is at the wrong level: Leaflet is a client-side map library. It *requests* information from a server. That server can provide some information, or none at all - it could provide png, gif, jpeg, or anything. If your server supports `.jpg` output, just change the `.png` at the end of this url to `.jpg` and it'll work. But if it doesn't, this question is in the scope of your server, rather than Leaflet.